# Setting up elasticsearch in a Jhipster / react / mongo DB project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, elasticsearch, jhipster

can anyone provide any guidance regarding setting up a jhipster project with elasticsearch (while using mongoDB)? I have followed the docs in jhipster but I think I'm missing a step to index my entities into elasticsearch.

There is the reindexing tool, but this is made for angular and SQL DBs which are sufficiently different to leave me a bit stuck.
Here is what i've done so far -

1. Changed my yo-rc file to be     "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
2. Rerun the 'jhipster' to generate the needed code.
3. Rerun 'jhipster entity ' to setup more needed code.
4. set up a docker instance of elasticsearch to run in dev.
5. If i browse to http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index, the page returns only 'user'.

Also, as you would expect given no.5 above, when I perform a search on my entity listing page (which has correctly been added), I get a 500 error with the following message -

"jhipster org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.NoSuchIndexException: Index [entityName] not found.; nested exception is"

From reading, I was kind of expecting the indexing to happen automatically on startup, although the docs do say you need a reindexing service to sync data. So my questions are -

1. How should the initial index be done? Do I manually need to do this?
2. How do you go about reindexing? Any guidance here would be appreciated (note my DB is Mongo), I am presuming I would use a @Scheduling / Quartz type piece of code, but I'm not really sure how the indexing is done.

cheers
david

Comment: I'm half clueless on this, too. Elasticsearch Reindexer seems to be the way to go for initial reindexing, but I'm using react, not angular, and this generator only generates for angular. See https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer

Comment: yea, i gave up in the end (i was also using react), the support for react doesn't seem as strong as angular.